# Export to markdown preview should read back to cv not back to profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When you go to /export/markdown-preview there is a button on the top right corner allowing you to **Export to Markdown**.  Next to that button is a hyperlink which is **back to profile**.  This is mislabeled, it should read **back to cv** not back to profile:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix pushed to production, thanks for the report!